# AP hotspot connected but net is not shared

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I set up a hotspot using Access Point hotspot,and my android phone is connected to the hotspot, but i am unable to access the internet on the phone, though it shows connected. I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I figured out the problem myself. The firewall was restricting the access to internet. hope this helps out others facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. It would be great if you can add this an answer to your own question as you've figured it out. Also, add in-detail if possible as it may help another later on. :)

Comment: Hi @user287772 i am facing the same problem  please post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

The firewall was restricting the access to internet. If you're using the GUI version of the firewall, it is as simple as opening the firewall and disabling it.
This should solve all problems.

Answer (score 1):

Sudheer: for Internet navigation through a hotspot to work you must enable forwarding on the hotspot machine, and configure NATting on it's firewall.

Comment: Please consider adding more details to this answer. It's very generic now